multiprocess not working correctly (Windows, Python2)
So I run this:
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
def ghello():
    print ("hello world g")
    
def fhello():
    print("hello world f")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=fhello)
    p.start()
    time.sleep(0.75)
    q = Process(target=ghello)
    q.start()
    exit(0)

But the two prints are not being displayed, why?
also what if I don't want to put the Process calls inside the magic method? How to execute this program without using if __name__ == "__main__": under Windows and Python 2?
UPDATE:
I would like to call the two processes as follows:
class TestingProcesses(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ....
    def ghello(self):
        print ("hello world g")

    def fhello(self):
        print("hello world f")

    def call_processes(self):
        p = Process(target=self.fhello)
        p.start()
        q = Process(target=self.ghello)
        q.start()
...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = TestingProcesses()
    # do something then start the processes...
    obj.call_processes()
....
    


The exit(0) must be inside the if __name__ == "__main__": guard. Everything outside of the guard is executed in every subprocess, therefore the guard is necessary (at least on Windows).

my bad, correct me if Im wrong, how to launch two seperate processes in Windows in Python 2 inside a program? still the prints are NOT executed in this case

What means "separate" here? You start two separate subprocesses in the code.

You can try to uncomment the joins (correctly indented) but it should actually work without them.

1)the print doesn't show any string, 2) how to launch two processes inside a program (as opposed to in its entry)


Unfortunately I have currently no idea what is going on. 2) Sorry but I don't understand. A "program" is not precisely defined, therefore I don't know what "inside" a program or "entry" should mean here.


if __name__ == "__main__": is the entry of a script or not? I would like to execute the two processes in a method of a class instead.

Please update your question showing how you want a method of a class to be called. Surely we can add the creation of two processes there.

The line checks if the name of the running module is __main__ which means it is the module (aka script) directly called from commandline. If it has a different name it was either imported as module from other code or it runs as subprocess created by the multiprocessing mechanism.

@quamrana pls check the update with the requested code

Should fhello and ghello also be methods of the class? This could make things more complicated (objects of the class must be picklable in this case). Apart from that it should work as shown.

indeed, they should, I adjusted that

As I wrote this should work if the object is picklable. If it isn't, an error message will tell it.

no error messages, the program exits normally

Sorry to ask what may seem like a silly question, but why are you using an obsolete Python version? Is there perhaps something else you're not telling us about the environment?

this should be reported as a major Python bug,. nothing else to tell you

Even if it is a bug, probably none of the developers will care about it.

Re how to use this without magic methods, just put it in any regular method and then invoke that in your file. You don't have to check whether your file is the first invoked by python even though it has advantages to it usually.

sure thing, thanks anyway, i'm out.

@Ulrich could you show us how?

Why are you not calling join() on the two Process objects?

When processes are run like these are, there is no visible console, by default. You may redirect the standard output to your main python project and print in the current terminal session.
Here's a redirect example using Python's subprocess
import subprocess

Start a process and redirect its standard output
process = subprocess.Popen(['your_command', 'arg1', 'arg2'], 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

Read the output incrementally
for line in process.stdout:
    print("Output:", line.strip())


could you explain further with an example?

is there a way not to use subprocess? then redirecting the sd outpud through for example IOString()

not working either btw

It's possible that the calls to print() in each of the subprocesses have not completed before you call exit(). You should wait for the processes to end before exiting.
If you want to run this without the typical check for __main__ (as explained in the documentation) you need to ensure that new processes are forked rather than spawned. However, you cannot do this on Windows.
The following code runs without error on MacOS (where the default start method is spawn). However, I do not recommend this technique. Also, I have no idea how this might run in an obsolete Python 2.x environment.
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import set_start_method

class TestingProcesses:
    def __init__(self):
        set_start_method("fork")

    def ghello(self):
        print("hello world g")

    def fhello(self):
        print("hello world f")

    def call_processes(self):
        targets = self.ghello, self.fhello
        procs = [Process(target=target) for target in targets]
        for proc in procs:
            proc.start()
        for proc in procs:
            proc.join()

obj = TestingProcesses()
# do something then start the processes...
obj.call_processes()


this example is not useful for me, your first hypothesis that it should wait for the processes to spawn is not correct because I checked using time.sleep(10) after the proc.start() and still no message shown
